# Is there a way to get input from a def function?

Tags: python

I was wondering if it's possible to get the only input from a def function.

```
def choose():
while True:
    try:
        pick = float(input("Enter any number that isn't 0 "))
        if pick != 0:
            break
        else:
            pick = float(input("Try again! Enter any number that isn't 0 "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
        continue
    else:
        break
  choose()
```

I will try to be as clear as possible. Can you take the `pick` input from `choose()` and store it somewhere else. Say like when your done inputting the number you want.

Can you run:

```
print(pick + 15)
```

or you can't take the input from the `choose()` at all. I would just like to know. Cause if so I don't even know how to do so. So I would appreciate the advice.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is your problem? A ``def`` can ``return`` arbitrary values, it does not matter where these come from.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear, but you could just `return pick` from `choose()` and then run `print(choose() + 15)`. Don't know if that's what you want

Comment: Any basic Python tutorial will tell you how to define a function that returns a value.

Comment: Where would I put the return pick at?

Comment: If you are asking if you can extract the value of a local variable from a pre-defined function, the answer is no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access local variables from outside the function. The function should return the value, and you can assign that to another variable.

```
def choose():
    while True:
        try:
            pick = float(input("Enter any number that isn't 0 "))
            if pick != 0:
                return pick
            else:
                print("Try again. The number has to be non-zero!")
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")

choice = choose()
print(choice + 15)
```

You also shouldn't ask for input in the `else:` block, because it's going to ask again when the loop repeats. Just print the error message there, without reading input.

You don't need the `continue` statement, since loops automatically continue unless the repetition condition becomes false (which can never happen with `while True:`) or you execute a `break` or `return` statement to leave the loop.